# Find the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion $(1 + ax + bx^2)^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Find the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(1 + ax + bx^2)^n$

One approach would be: 
Let $p = 1+ax$ 
and $q = bx^2$ 
Now expand $(p+q)^n$ and then expand $p$ and $q$ individually. But that is so clumsy. Can we derive a direct formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: use the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$(a+b+c)^n=\sum_{i+j+k=n}\frac{n!}{i!j!k!}a^ib^jc^k$$

Comment: $\Huge{+1}$ for the excellent hint!