# Multinomial Theorem application

Tags: multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

Here is my question:

> Find the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1 + 2x - 3x^2)^5.$

I know that I am suppose to use the multinomial theorem, but I don't know how to. The proof that's in my textbook approaches it using partial derivatives, as opposed to combinations and I was expecting an example of how to find the coefficient of some expression, but there wasn't any. I've been reading a couple other threads about how to find coefficients of terms and I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201052/find-the-coefficient-of-x3y2z3-in-the-expansion-2x3y-4zw9) link and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416516/find-the-coefficient-of-xm-in-the-expansion-1-ax-bx2n) link as well. After reading through everything, here is my approach:

$$(1)^j(2x)^k(-3x^2)^p,$$ where $(j + k + p )= 5$. Since I want to look for the coefficient of the $x^3$ term, do I have to find combinations such that $(j + k + p) = 5?$ So for example, let $j = 1, k = 1$ and $p = 1$. But this doesn't add up to $5$... and this is where I got stuck Perhaps there is a different approach. By the way, wolfram gave me a [coefficient](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(1%2B2x-3x%5E2)%5E5) of $-40$.

I don't know why this problem in particular is hard for me. I can do a similar problem of the same type.

**EDIT**
So as the answer below suggests, this problem can be solved using the binomial theorem, but how would it look like if we used the multinomial theorem?

Comment: Well, first, you think about HOW you can form a x^3.

Comment: You can achieve this with an x and an x^2, or 3 x's.

Comment: Rewrite your expression as (p+q+r)^5 and compute two cases, then multiply by appropriate poewrs (the coefficients of x and x^2 aren't 1

Comment: What two cases?

Comment: `Since I want to look for the coefficient of the x^3  term, do I have to find combinations such that (j+k+p)=5?` You are looking for the $3^{rd}$ power term. Why `=5`?

Comment: Ah so $j + k + p = 3$. But that still doesn't clear up my question. Am I suppose to figure out how many ways to select power such that they add up to $3$?

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 Indeed. In fact, that's been pointed out in previous comments already.

Comment: Ah I see. So there should be 10 ways of selecting variables such that they add up to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok but you could just use the Binomial Theorem instead

$$(1+x(2-3x))^5=1+5x(2-3x)+10x^2(2-3x)^2+10x^3(2-3x)^3+...$$

So you don't have to look very hard to find the coefficient of $x^3$ which is $$-120+80$$

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: Find the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+2x-3x^2)$.

The first step is to set up a term as ${(1)^a}{(2x)^b}{(-3x^2)^c}$. $a+b+c=5$. Then you create 2 cases where the terms when multiplied, have the factor $x^3$.

> Case 1: $a=3, b=1,$ and $ c=1$.

This case states ${(1)^3}{(2x)^1}{(-3x^2)}^1=cx^3$, where c is a real number. First, you need to find the number of ways you can order these cases. That is like asking how many permutations there are of "$aaabc$". That is equal to $\frac{5!}{3!1!1!}=20$. Then you have to find the products of the coefficients of the monomials(raised to their respective powers) in ${(1)^3}{(2x)^1}{(-3x^2)}^1$. That 
is equal to $(1^3)(2^1)(-3)^1=(2)(-3)=-6$. Then you multiply $-6$ by $20$ to get $-120$, the coefficient of $x^3$ in Case 1.

> Case 2: $a=2, b=3,$ and $c=0$

Using the method from Case 1, You get $\frac{5!}{2!3!0!}=10$ and $(1^2)(2^3)((-3)^0)=8$. Multiply those 2 together to get $80$, the coefficent of $x^3$ in Case 2.

To get the final answer, add the results from Case 1 and Case 2, which gives you $-120+80=$

> $-40$